# Determining values for active low-pass output filter for DAC

Tags: audio, dac, active-filter, component-selection

I'm trying to use a [PCM1780](https://www.ti.com/product/PCM1780) as DAC for my audio circuit. The datasheet shows the following recommended output schematic for this DAC, for which I'm trying to choose component values (because they do not provide these): [image: Output filter circuit diagram]

According to the datasheet this is a second-order Butterworth filter using the multiple feedback arrangement, with a single supply op-amp (I only have a 5V supply). I need a gain of 0 dBand a cut-off frequency of 24 kHz.

I've had a go at determining the resistor and capacitor values, and using TI's [Analog Engineer's Circuit Coookbook: Amplifiers](https://www.ti.com/lit/eb/slyy137b/slyy137b.pdf) (page 230) I've determined two options with the following values (which come close to available components):

| Component | Option 1 | Option 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R<sub>1</sub> = R<sub>2</sub> = R<sub>3</sub> | 5.1 kΩ | 91 kΩ |
| C<sub>1</sub> | 613 pF | 34 pF |
| C<sub>2</sub> | 2758 pF | 155pF |

Simulating these using Tina-TI for a sine wave, I think I get sufficient results: [image: Gain to frequency]

However, because I have no real experience designing these kinds of circuits, I would really appreciate it if you could give any feedback on these values and the component choice, and if there is a better way to calculate them.

Basically, I now have the following questions:

- Do these component values make any sense?
- Is this result good enough for a cheap DAC?
- Can I just use ceramic capacitors for C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>?
- How do I choose values for the resistors and capacitors behind the op-amp? I'm sure R<sub>5</sub> is to balance the connection, but what is the point of R<sub>4</sub> and that capacitor?

Comment: I would use f-3dB = 2*24kHz, as the audio is distorted otherwise.

Comment: According to [this application bulletin](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbaa055), the filter _should_ have a cut-off frequency of 24kHz, and they even want -6dB at that point (p. 6). I don't know how I would achieve that using a second-order active filter.

Comment: Pelican:  Go with option #1, the capacitance values are easier to work with.  I'm just guessing that you simulated using an ideal op-amp, A realistic op-amp has input capacitance in range of several pF which will could give a small amount of error if you go as low at 34pF. At 34pF you also need to start worrying about trace capacitance.

Comment: On C1 and C2, you can use ceramics if cost is an issue but keep in mind that they usually have poor tolerance and a temperature coefficient.  Get 10% NP0 or CG0 if you can.